# join 3 tables with one to many and one to one relationship

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
    Memory_map:
        - Id
        - Memory_map_version
        - Product_id_hex
        - Parameter --------------------> want to add this to Histogram table
        
    
    Histogram_read:
        - Id
        - Memory_map_version -------> these 2 keys are referencing to the Memory_map table
        - Product_id_hex ---------> these 2 keys are referencing to the Memory_map table
        
    Histogram:
        - Id
        - Histogram_read_id
```

The relationship is:

```
Histogram_read (one) --> histogram(many)
        
Memory_map (one) --> histogram_read(one)
```

So Now I want to create a NEW Histogram table with the [Parameter] field from Memory_map table added to the original Histogram table.

Because Memory_map (one) --> histogram_read(one) is a ONE-TO-ONE relationship, so I will need to join these two tables first before I join the Histogram_read table with Memory_map table to add the [Parameter] field to Histogram table.

So, should I do a inner join first between Histogram_read and Histogram based on Histogram_read_id? (since Histogram_read_id is a key referencing the Histogram_read table records), but since it's a ONE-TO-MANY relationship, is it ok to do the INNER JOIN?

And Because I only want all records and columns from Histogram table - just with [Parameter] field added, so if I join the Histogram_read table with Histogram table before I join the Histogram_read table with the Memory_map table, how do I make sure the final table of Histogram wasn't messed up by columns in the Histogram_read table?

I have this following query but it doesn't work:

```
create view histogram_new
as 
select M.parameter, Nest.* from memory_map M
RIGHT JOIN 
(select * from histogram_read R
INNER JOIN histogram H
ON H.histogram_read_id = R.id) Nest
ON M.memory_map_version = Nest.memory_map_version 
AND M.product_id_hex = Nest.product_id_hex;
```

I'm confused about the 3 tables join with one=to-many and one-to-one relationship, I am not sure what the logic should be. anyone can helps? THANKS!

Comment: can you lease add data and CREATE TABLE for a [mre] to your question. i am unsure what the result is you expect

Answer (score 1):

With relationship cardinalities between tables, you should think of the outcome of `INNER JOINING` those tables as multiplicative per row, in a sense. In a **one-to-one** relationship you'll always end up with, at most, *1 x 1* record per record in the **smaller** table. For example if your `memory_map` table has 10 records and your `histogram_read` table has 5 records, the most records you could possibly end up with is 5 records.  Those would be whichever 5 records in `memory_map` that had a related record to the 5 in `histogram_read`.

In a **one-to-many** relationship, the above is similarly true except the **many** table dictates how many rows will be returned per row in the **one** table. So now the multiplicative relationship is *1 x N* where N is the number of related rows in the **many** table to 1 particular row in the **one** table. For example, if your `histogram_read` table has 5 records, and your `histogram` table has 20, the most records an `INNER JOIN` could possibly return is 20, if all 20 records related to the 5 records in `histogram_read`. (Then you'd be getting every row back from `histogram` in that case.)

So in short, with an `INNER JOIN`, for a **one-to-one** relationship, the most records you can end up with is the total number of records in the **smaller** table between the join. For a **one-to-many** relationship, the most records would be the total number of records in the **larger** table.

The last thing to keep in mind is `INNER JOIN` only returns rows that match between both tables of the join clause, and filters out the rows that don't match. `OUTER JOIN` like a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (`LEFT JOIN` for short) or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` (`RIGHT JOIN` for short) will always return **all** rows from the table on that side of the join clause, and will `NULL` out the columns of the table on the other side of the join clause where there aren't any matches. For example, if your `histogram_read` table has 5 records and `histogram` has 20 records, and only 12 of the records in `histogram` related to the 5 records in `histogram_read` then with an `INNER JOIN` between the two tables you would only get 12 records. But with an `OUTER JOIN` that points to the `histogram` table, such as `FROM histogram_read RIGHT JOIN histogram`, will ensure you get all 20 records back from the `histogram` table, with `NULL` values in the columns from `histogram_read` for the 8 rows that didn't match from `histogram`.

All of that being said, I don't see anything inherently wrong with the query you wrote, other than the `INNER JOIN` in your subquery possibly filtering rows out of `histogram` if they don't match `histogram_read`. You can use all `OUTER JOIN` clauses to prevent that from happening, and you actually don't even need a subquery. Here's an example query that should essentially produce what you're looking for:

```
SELECT M.parameter, R.*, H.* -- You shouldn't use *, it's bad practice, anti-pattern, and potentially bad for performance, instead explicitly list only the columns you need
FROM histogram H
LEFT JOIN histogram_read R
    ON H.histogram_read_id = R.id
LEFT JOIN memory_map M
    ON M.memory_map_version = R.memory_map_version 
    AND M.product_id_hex = R.product_id_hex
```

With **one-to-many** relationships, I personally prefer to start with the **many** table in my joins, but it doesn't really matter, as long as you use the correct `OUTER JOIN`. In this case, because the **many** table is on the left side of the join clause, we need to use a `LEFT JOIN`. The above query will return all rows from `histogram`, with the `parameter` column from `memory_map`, with `NULL` values for wherever there wasn't a match on a record between `histogram` and the rest of the tables.